# Permissions for DBMS_JOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

We have a program in which we call the dbms_job through a proceudre, for some requirements we were asked to remove the permissions on the job and not allow it to exeucte,

I have tried revoking the grants from the job,

both,

```
revoke execute on dbms_job from user;
revoke all on dbms_job from user;
```

This works fine if we directly submit a job in the schmea, it says, no procedure defined,  but when we run it from the procedure the job executes succesfully,

any ways to avoid this scenario or anything else to be checked.?

Comment: What user owns the procedure?  What user calls the procedure?  Is the procedure an invoker's rights procedure or a definer's rights procedure?  What user are you revoking privileges on `dbms_job` from?

Comment: the user that owns the procedure and the user that calls the procedure are same.

Comment: @anudeepks please make clear, which user owns (i.e. user A) the procedure, which user (i.e. user B) calls the procedure and for which user you revoked the rights